# How to draw a circle instead of a marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am using the following and works fine:

```
      var markers = [],
          markerCluster;

      for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        var pin = coords[i].split(',');
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0],
            pin[1]);
        (function() {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          }),
          circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            radius: 30.48,
            fillColor: '#ff007f',
            strokeColor: '#ff007f',
            strokeOpacity: 0.75,
            strokeWeight: 20
          });
          circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
          circle.bindTo('map', marker, 'map');
          markers.push(marker);
        })();
      };
      markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'
      });
```

However it is still drawing the pin too while I am only looking into showing the circle

Comment: If you make your circle into an icon you can use it as a key/value in your marker object. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: @ecg8 thanks, I tried but I couldn't work it out. At the end I've put               `marker.setVisible(false);` right after `markers.push(marker);` and hides the pin while showing the circle. On another note, do you have any idea how do I set the cluster radius? I see 2 markers clustered while they are pretty far, is there any option? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) only manages [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/#marker) objects.

One option would be to modify that source to manage [google.maps.Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle) objects.

However, probably simplest to just make the icons for your existing markers a 1px  transparent PNG, then let the MarkerClusterer manage the markers (which are bound to the associated circles).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      // 1x1 transparent PNG data URL
      icon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    }),
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c7pnsd1q/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map zoomed in on two "markers"]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    }
  });

  var markers = [],
    markerCluster;

  for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    var pin = coords[i].split(',');
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0],
      pin[1]);
    (function() {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          icon: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
        }),
        circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          radius: 30.48,
          fillColor: '#ff007f',
          strokeColor: '#ff007f',
          strokeOpacity: 0.75,
          strokeWeight: 20
        });
      circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
      circle.bindTo('map', marker, 'map');
      markers.push(marker);
    })();
  };
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'
  });

}
var coords = [
  "-31.563910, 147.154312",
  "-33.718234, 150.363181",
  "-33.727111, 150.371124",
  "-33.848588, 151.209834",
  "-33.851702, 151.216968",
  "-34.671264, 150.863657",
  "-35.304724, 148.662905",
  "-36.817685, 175.699196",
  "-36.828611, 175.790222",
  "-37.750000, 145.116667",
  "-37.759859, 145.128708",
  "-37.765015, 145.133858",
  "-37.770104, 145.143299",
  "-37.773700, 145.145187",
  "-37.774785, 145.137978",
  "-37.819616, 144.968119",
  "-38.330766, 144.695692",
  "-39.927193, 175.053218",
  "-41.330162, 174.865694",
  "-42.734358, 147.439506",
  "-42.734358, 147.501315",
  "-42.735258, 147.438000",
  "-43.999792, 170.463352"
]
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/v3-utility-library@07f15d84/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<!-- was https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js -->
```

Comment: thanks a lot, at the end I simply did `circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
              circle.bindTo('map', marker, 'map');
              markers.push(marker);
              marker.setVisible(false);` this way I am drawing the circles but I am hiding the pin